# Issue with the strtok function in C: it only returns one token

Tags: c, shell, loops, environment-variables, strtok

Can someone please help me figure out why my code is not assigning the next element the `strtok` function returns to my index? It attaches the first return of `strtok`, but not any of the following ones. So my while loop only runs once. I am not sure what is going on, much help appreciated. Thanks!

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    int main(int ac, char **av, char **env)
    {
        char **token;
        const char *deli = ":";
        char *path = "PATH=";
        char *hold;
        int i, j, k = 0, inputSize = 100;
    
        int count;
    
        token = malloc(inputSize * sizeof(char));
            if(token == NULL)
            {
                exit;
            }
    
            for (count = 0; count < inputSize; count++)
            {
                token[count] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (inputSize));
    
                if (token[count] == NULL)
                {
                    for (count -= 1; count >= 0; count--)
                    {
                        free(token[count]);
                    }
                    free(token);
    
                    return (0);
                }
        }
    //this loop gets PATH
        for (i = 0; env[i] != NULL; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
            if (path[j] != env[i][j])
                    break;
            }
            if (j == 5)
                break;
        }
    
        strtok(env[i], deli);
    
        hold = strtok(env[i], deli);
    
        while (hold != NULL)
        {
            token[k] = (char*)hold;
            printf("%s\n", token[k]);
            k++;
            hold = strtok(NULL, deli);
        }
        return (0);
    }
```

Comment: Note that it is `exit();` and not `exit;`. The latter do nothing.

Comment: For `strtok`, for a given buffer you pass the buffer address on the first call and pass `NULL` for the remaining calls/tokens

Comment: You should delete the first statement of strtok(), this function will modify the env_i content and the next call to this fonction will not work as expected.

Comment: thanks guys! deleting the first call helped

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues causing problems. When using `strtok()` the first call makes used of the pointer itself, e.g. `strtok (p, delims);` while all subsequent call use `NULL` in place of the pointer, e.g. `strtok (NULL, delim);`.

`strtok()` modifies the string it operates on. You may want to make a copy of the environment string holding the PATH before altering the original.

You are also complicating locating the PATH environment string and then removing the `"PATH="` portion so the remainder can be tokenized into the individual path components. A simply want to approach this is to use `strncmp()` to search for the prefix `"PATH="` and then advance past the first five characters in the string.

You can do that simply with `PREFIX` defined as `"PATH="` and `prefixlen = strlen(PREFIX);` as:

```
    char path[PATH_MAX] = "",               /* storage for copy of environment string */
        *p = path,                          /* pointer - general use */
        **tokens = NULL;                    /* pointer to pointer for path components */
    ...
    for (int i = 0; env[i]; i++)            /* find PREFIX in environment */
        if (strncmp (env[i], PREFIX, prefixlen) == 0) {
            strcpy (p, env[i] + prefixlen); /* copy path from env to path */
            break;
        }
```

If you initialize your the storage for `path` to the empty-string or all zero, you can confirm the `PATH` environment variable was found by testing your copy contains a string, e.g.

```
    if (!*p) {  /* if PREFIX not found */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: '%s' not found in environment.\n", PREFIX);
        return 1;
    }
```

When you use `strtok()` to separate the path components in `path` for access through the *pointer-to-pointer-to* `char`, you must allocated a pointer for each component (and an additional pointer if you want to provide a sentinel `NULL` as the final pointer marking the end). While you generally would want to allocate a block of pointers, with the relative few path components (less than 100), you can simply `realloc` and add a pointer for each token found. When you `realloc`, you always use a temporary pointer to prevent overwriting your original pointer with `NULL` if `realloc` fails.

You also need to allocate storage for each of the path components ensuring storage for the string (+1) for the nul-terminating character. You can use a simple `for()` loop with `strtok()` to tokenize your copy of the environment string similar to:

```
    /* loop moving ep (end-pointer) to next DELIM in p or last token */
    for (p = strtok (p, DELIM); p; p = strtok (NULL, DELIM)) {
        size_t  len = strlen(p);            /* length of token */
        /* realloc pointers using temporary pointer
         * adding two more than index to set sentinel NULL as last pointer
         * (sentinel NULL is optional, just add 1 if not wanted)
         */
        void *tmp = realloc (tokens, (ndx + 2) * sizeof *tokens);
        if (!tmp) {                                 /* validate realloc */
            perror ("realloc-tokens");
            break;
        }
        tokens = tmp;                               /* assign new block to tokens */
        tokens[ndx + 1] = NULL;                     /* set sentinel NULL */
        if (!(tokens[ndx] = malloc (len + 1))) {    /* allocate/validate string storage */
            perror ("malloc-tokens[ndx]");
            tokens[ndx] = NULL;
            break;
        }
        memcpy (tokens[ndx++], p, len + 1);         /* copy path component */
    }
```

Putting it altogether in a short example you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#ifndef PATH_MAX
#define PATH_MAX 4096
#endif

#define PREFIX "PATH="  /* constants for PREFIX and DELIM */
#define DELIM ":\n"

int main (int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
    char path[PATH_MAX] = "",               /* storage for copy of environment string */
        *p = path,                          /* pointer - general use */
        **tokens = NULL;                    /* pointer to pointer for path components */
        
    size_t  prefixlen = strlen (PREFIX),    /* prefix length */
            ndx = 0;                        /* path tokens index */
    
    for (int i = 0; env[i]; i++)            /* find PREFIX in environment */
        if (strncmp (env[i], PREFIX, prefixlen) == 0) {
            strcpy (p, env[i] + prefixlen); /* copy path from env to path */
            break;
        }
    
    if (!*p) {  /* if PREFIX not found */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: '%s' not found in environment.\n", PREFIX);
        return 1;
    }
    
    puts ("\nfull path:\n");    /* show full path to create tokens from */
    puts (p);
    
    /* loop moving ep (end-pointer) to next DELIM in p or last token */
    for (p = strtok (p, DELIM); p; p = strtok (NULL, DELIM)) {
        size_t  len = strlen(p);            /* length of token */
        /* realloc pointers using temporary pointer
         * adding two more than index to set sentinel NULL as last pointer
         * (sentinel NULL is optional, just add 1 if not wanted)
         */
        void *tmp = realloc (tokens, (ndx + 2) * sizeof *tokens);
        if (!tmp) {                                 /* validate realloc */
            perror ("realloc-tokens");
            break;
        }
        tokens = tmp;                               /* assign new block to tokens */
        tokens[ndx + 1] = NULL;                     /* set sentinel NULL */
        if (!(tokens[ndx] = malloc (len + 1))) {    /* allocate/validate string storage */
            perror ("malloc-tokens[ndx]");
            tokens[ndx] = NULL;
            break;
        }
        memcpy (tokens[ndx++], p, len + 1);         /* copy path component */
    }
    
    puts ("\npath components:\n");                  /* output separated tokens */
    for (size_t i = 0; tokens && tokens[i]; i++) {  /* loop until sentinel NULL */
        puts (tokens[i]);
        free (tokens[i]);                           /* free string storage */
    }
    free (tokens);                                  /* free pointers */
    
    (void)argc;     /* cast to prevent -Wunused warnings */
    (void)argv;
}
```

(**note:** the `for()` loop condition `tokens && tokens[i]` will handle the case where the initial allocation with `realloc()` returns `NULL` avoiding the dereference of `tokens[0]`. You can provide a separate `if (!tokens) { perror ("initial allocation failed"); return 1; }` above the output loop if you prefer)

**Example Use/Output**

Compiling and running the program would result in output similar to:

```
$ ./bin/path_tokens

full path:

/opt/kde3/bin:/home/david/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/lib/qt3/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin

path components:

/opt/kde3/bin
/home/david/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/lib/qt3/bin
/sbin
/usr/sbin
/usr/local/sbin
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/path_tokens
==22643== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22643== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22643== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22643== Command: ./bin/path_tokens
==22643==

full path:

/opt/kde3/bin:/home/david/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/lib/qt3/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin

path components:

/opt/kde3/bin
/home/david/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/lib/qt3/bin
/sbin
/usr/sbin
/usr/local/sbin
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin
==22643==
==22643== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22643==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22643==   total heap usage: 21 allocs, 21 frees, 1,679 bytes allocated
==22643==
==22643== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==22643==
==22643== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22643== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

**Changes To Work On Windows and Linux**

Since windows uses the `';'` (semi-colon) for the path separator and prefixes the environment string with `"Path="`, while Linux uses `':'` (colon) for the separator and `"PATH="` as the prefix, with a simple preprocessor `#if .. #else .. #endif`, you can modify the program to work on both Widows and Linux. Simply replace the defines for `PREFIX` and `DELIM` with:

```
#if defined (_WIN64) || defined (_WIN32)
#define PREFIX "Path="  /* constants for PREFIX and DELIM on windows */
#define DELIM ";\r\n"
#else
#define PREFIX "PATH="  /* constants for PREFIX and DELIM on Linux */
#define DELIM ":\n"
#endif
```

**Example Use/Output on Windows**

The full path has been omitted since it would scroll for a thousand plus characters:

```
>bin\path_tokens_win.exe

full path:

<snipped -- too long>

path components:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Team Tools\Performance Tools
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\\MSBuild\15.0\bin
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16
C:\Windows\System32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\
C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\
C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Program Files\PuTTY\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Gpg4win\..\GnuPG\bin
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
c:\MinGW\bin
c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin
c:\gtk2\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja
```

(Microsoft certainly isn't shy about path size....)

There are several other options aside from `strtok()` that do not alter the original string. You can use `strpbrk()` similar to how you use `strtok()` manually advancing a start and end pointer to bracket and copy each component. You can use `strchr()` to locate each delimiter in essentially the same way. If you like working with indexes more than pointers, you can use `strcspn()` to get the number of characters between each delimiter. Of course you can also just use a loop working down then string manually locating each delimiter. How you do it is entirely up to you.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questins.

Comment: WOW!! This was amazing , thank you so much for the detailed response!!! I will definitely read this over several times again. Very detailed response. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your coding. Let me know if you need additional help.